# any() vs any(Class.class) Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

I am not able to understand why below two tests are not giving the same result.

```java
@Service
public class SomeManager{
    private final SomeDependency someDependency;
    
    @Autowired
    public SomeManager(SomeDependency someDependency){
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
    
    public List<returnType> methodToTest(Arg arg){
        List<JsonObject> jo = someDependency.search(arg);
        return jo.stream().map(returnType::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

Test with `any()`. This Test pass.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestMethodToTest(){
    @Test
    public void TestMethod(){
        SomeDependency someDependency = mock(SomeDependency.class);
        List<JsonObject> expected := \some valid list of JsonObject\
    
        // Here I used any() method.
        when(someDependency.search(any())).thenReturn(expected);
    
        SomeManager someManager = new SomeManager(someDependency);
        List<returnType> actual = someManager.methodToTest(any(Arg.class));
    
        assertArrayEquals(acutal.toArray(), expected.stream().map(returnType::parse).toArray());
        }
}
```

But since `search(Arg arg)` method of `SomeDependency` takes parameter of class `Arg` so I changed above test like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestMethodToTest(){
    @Test
    public void TestMethod(){
        SomeDependency someDependency = mock(SomeDependency.class);
        List<JsonObject> expected := \some valid list of JsonObject\

        // Here I used any(Arg.class) method.
        when(someDependency.search(any(Arg.class))).thenReturn(expected);
    
        SomeManager someManager = new SomeManager(someDependency);
        List<returnType> actual = someManager.methodToTest(any(Arg.class));
    
        assertArrayEquals(acutal.toArray(), expected.stream().map(returnType::parse).toArray());
        }
}
```

This second test fails with output `java.lang.AssertionError: array lengths differed, expected.length=1 actual.length=0`.What's the possible reason behind this?

**Note**: The value `expected.length=1` in output depends on what value is provided by the user as valid list of json objects in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that `any` matches null, while `anyClass` does not match null. See [ArgumentMatchers javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html):

- `any()` Matches anything, including nulls and varargs.
- `any​(Class<T> type)` Matches any object of given type, excluding nulls.

You are passing null to your method under test here:

```
List<returnType> actual = someManager.methodToTest(any(Arg.class));
```

`any()` returns null which you pass to method under test.

Note that using argument matchers this way is illegal - you should only call them inside calls to `when` and `verify`. You should pass a real instance of `Arg` to method under test.

See [Mockito javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

> Matcher methods like any(), eq() do not return matchers. Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value (usually null). This implementation is due to static type safety imposed by the java compiler. The consequence is that you cannot use any(), eq() methods outside of verified/stubbed method.

Comment: Thanks, btw is there any other way without creating an actual object of `Arg` class. Problem is I don't own `Arg` class so it would be better if somehow I mock it.

Comment: Not owning `Arg` class in not a problem - what matters is if you can instantiate it somehow. If you really cannot instantiate it, you can pass a mock - `mock(Arg.class)` - which is legal but a bit unusual - If your method under test is public, you expect being able to construct its arguments.